# Bash is redirecting output from command only after script has finished

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep

**Context**

Got a daft script that checks a process is running on a group of hosts, like a watchdog, as I say it's a daft script so bear in mind it isn't 'perfect' by scripting standards

**Problem**

I've ran `bash -x` and can see that the script finishes its first check without actually redirecting the output of the command to the file which is very frustrating, it means each host is actually being evaluated to the last hosts output

**Code**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE='OUTPUT'
for host in $(cat /etc/hosts | grep webserver.[2][1-2][0-2][0-9] | awk {' print $2 ' })

do ssh -n -f $host -i <sshkey> 'ps ax | grep myprocess | wc -l' > $FILE 2> /dev/null
cat $FILE
if grep '1' $FILE ; then
 echo "Process is NOT running on $host"
 cat $FILE
else
 cat $FILE
 echo "ALL OK on $host"
fi
cat $FILE
done
```

**Script traceback**

```
++ cat /etc/hosts
++ awk '{ print $2 }'
++ grep 'webserver.[2][1-2][0-2][0-9]'
+ for host in '$(cat /etc/hosts | grep webserver.[2][1-2][0-2][0-9] | awk {'\'' print $2 '\''})'
+ ssh -n -f webserver.2100 -i <omitted> 'ps ax | grep myprocess | wc -l'
+ cat OUTPUT
+ grep 1 OUTPUT
+ cat OUTPUT
+ echo 'ALL OK on webserver.2100'
ALL OK on webserver.2100
+ cat OUTPUT
+ printf 'webserver.2100 checked \n'
webserver.2100 checked 
+ for host in '$(cat /etc/hosts | grep webserver.[2][1-2][0-2][0-9] | awk {'\'' print $2 '\''})'
+ ssh -n -f webserver.2101 -i <omitted> 'ps ax | grep myprocess | wc -l'
+ cat OUTPUT
2
+ grep 1 OUTPUT
+ cat OUTPUT
2
+ echo 'ALL OK on webserver.2101'
ALL OK on webserver.2101
+ cat OUTPUT
2
+ printf 'webserver.2101 checked \n'
webserver.2101 checked
```

**Issue**

As you can see, it's registering nothing for the first host, then after it is done, it's piping the data into the file, then the second host is being evaluated for the previous hosts data...

I suspect its to do with redirection, but in my eyes this should work, it doesn't so it's frustrating.

Comment: I suggest to replace `ps ax | grep myprocess | wc -l` with `pgrep myprocess | wc -l`.

Comment: I think the issue is that for `weberserv.2100` the ssh command fails and therefore only outputs to `stderr`. Can you please check this by redirecting the error output to something other than `/dev/null`?

Comment: @jayant - I have verified that both hosts are online, they are both accessible

Comment: @DannyWatson No, you're misunderstanding what's happening. The ssh to the first host is returning *nothing* to stdout (probably because of an error of some sort; you'll have to remove the stderr redirect to find out). The ssh to the second host is returning "2" (probably because it's finding both the process you're looking for and `grep myprocess` -- this will happen intermittently with the method you're using, so use `pgrep` instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're assuming that `ps ax | grep myprocess` will always return at least one line (the grep process). I'm not sure that's true. I'd rewrite that like this:

```
awk '/webserver.[2][1-2][0-2][0-9]/ {print $2}' /etc/hosts | while IFS= read -r host; do
    output=$( ssh -n -f "$host" -i "$sshkey" 'ps ax | grep "[m]yprocess"' )
    if [[ -z "$output" ]]; then
        echo "Process is NOT running on $host"
    else
        echo "ALL OK on $host"
    fi
done
```

This trick `ps ax | grep "[m]yprocess"` effectively removes the grep process from the ps output:

- the *string* "**myprocess**" matches the *regular expression* "**[m]yprocess**" (that's the running "myprocess" process), but
- the *string* "**[m]yprocess**" does not match the *regular expression* "**[m]yprocess**" (that's the running "grep" process)

Comment: Interesting this seems to work, I've substituted the `ps ax` to `pgrep` instead as it makes more sense if I'm just looking for a process...


Can you advise why this writes to the file then and there and why my script only wrote to a file after checking the condition?

Comment: I'm sure that your code *did* write to the file, it just wrote zero bytes to it